React: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@styles/footer.module.css' in 'N:\projectname\web2\src\components'
I've got an error while the React App was starting.
I've got this error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@styles/footer.module.css' in 'N:\project name\web2\src\components'

and this too,
TS2307: Cannot find module '@components/dashboard' or its corresponding type declarations.
    1 | import App from "./App";
    2 | import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
  > 3 | import Dashboard from "@components/dashboard";
      |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    4 | import Home from "./components/home";
    5 | import Product from "./components/product";
    6 | import Shop from "./components/shop";

And I'm using extra library: react-app-alias, react-app-rewired,
because I want to import like this:
import ../../styles/footer.module.css // not like this
import "@styles/footer.module.css" // like this

That's my tsconfig.json & tsonfig.paths.json:
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

// tsconfig.paths.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@styles/*": ["./styles/*"],
      "@components/*": ["./components/*"]
    }
  }
}

And that's my react-app-alias config:
// config-overrides.js
const { aliasWebpack, aliasJest, configPaths } = require("react-app-alias");

const options = {
  alias: configPaths("./tsconfig.paths.json"),
  tsconfig: "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  baseUrl: "./src",
};

module.exports = aliasWebpack(options);
module.exports.jest = aliasJest(options);

Lastly, that's my project hierarchy
web2
-- node_modules
-- public
-- src
  -- assets
  -- components
    -- components (like home, login)
  -- context
  -- interfaces
  -- styles
    -- component styles
  -- App.tsx
  -- index.tsx
  -- router.tsx
  -- typing.d.ts
-- .gitignore
-- config-overrides.js (react-app-alias settings)
-- package-lock.json 
-- package.json
-- README.md
-- tsconfig.json
-- tsconfig.paths.json

I installed some extra library: react-app-alias, react-app-rewired.
And I started the React App and it started working right away.
But, when I tried to edit all the .css file to .module.css file, this error occured

Welcome to stackoverflow, it's not recommended to use baseUrl in this case, you can simply use paths without baseUrl, also a better approach in your tsconfig.paths.json would be to add "@/*": ["./src/*"], this is similar to the Next.js default import alias. Another thing is that i don't understand why you are separating tsconfig.json and tsconfig.paths.json, they are in the same directory and they do not overlap.
